# Page/Table Load Animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, animation

I have two pages with tables. These tables are populated using `ng-repeat`. When I switch between the pages the page loading is very choppy and sudden.

[image]

When the page loads, the footer is half way up the page just below the table heading then the table is loaded and the page fixes itself to how it should look.

How can I improve this or avoid this? It's not very smooth or visually pleasing.

One of the pages:

https://codeshare.io/GL78NN

Comment: can you pls add the source you are working or a minimal working example.

Comment: @SamuelJMathew I've added a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to make your footer fixed at the bottom if the screen.

```
footer{
    width:100%;
    bottom:0px;
    position:fixed;
}
```